# is this a special way to turn off the command-echoing feature in a bat file?

Tags: batch-file

i am learning ruby lately.
there is a rake.bat in the bin directory of ruby.
i find a line of code `@"ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*` in it.
why do they add @ before "ruby.exe".
is this a special way to turn off the command-echoing feature in a bat file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep! Putting `@` before a command suppresses echoing the command. If you want to do it globally, put `@echo off` at the top of the batch file. `echo off` disables command echoing, and the `@` keeps the `echo off` command itself from being echoed.